# Cat command with pipe working in bash but not in script

Tags: bash, cat

Pretty simple script, but I am stuck.

It connects to a battery balancer, spits out the info into a json formatted file. I then have a pipe the output into jq to obtain the info I need.
It works in the bash shell, but not in the script:

Here is the script:

```bash
echo "Checking battery voltages"
jkbms -p 3C:A5:19:7B:28:09 -o json > /home/bms/batt.log
echo cat /home/bms/batt.log | jq -r '.highest_cell_voltage'
echo "done"
```

The cat line shows this in the script output:

```bash
Checking battery voltages
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 4
done
```

From the shell it works as expected:

```bash
cat /home/bms/batt.log | jq -r '.highest_cell_voltage'
4.152044773101807
```

I have tried enclosing the whole cat command in quotes etc, but I am at a loss.

This, however, works:

```bash
echo "Checking battery voltages"
jkbms -p 3C:A5:19:7B:28:09 -o json > /home/bms/batt.log
batt=$(cat /home/bms/batt.log)
echo $batt | jq -r '.highest_cell_voltage'
#echo /usr/bin/cat /home/bms/batt.log
echo "done"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> jkbms -p 3C:A5:19:7B:28:09 -o json > /home/bms/batt.log
> echo cat /home/bms/batt.log | jq -r '.highest_cell_voltage'
> ```

The `echo` here is wrong. By the way, you can simplify the above to:

```
jkbms -p 3C:A5:19:7B:28:09 -o json|tee /home/bms/batt.log|jq -r '.highest_cell_voltage'
```

> If I need to print the output of the comand on the screen, how do i do it without using echo?

If you want the saved output in `/home/bms/batt.log`, you can `cat /home/bms/batt.log` anytime.
If you want *to print the output of the comand on the screen* only at the time of execution, you can `tee /dev/tty` instead of `tee /home/bms/batt.log`.
If at the time of execution you want the output on screen as well as in the log file, you can `tee /home/bms/batt.log /dev/tty` at once.

Comment: Thanks for the simplication, but I need to understand how to do what I need above, as will need to be logging various things into variables to compare values.
If I need to print the output of the comand on the screen, how do i do it without using echo?

Comment: I amended the answer.